# Ошибка в матрице

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, матрицы

я попытался выполнить задание:

> Добавить строки после каждой четной строки матрицы

но к сожалению в этот месте у меня крах программы что не так я сделал ?

```
    for (int i = 1; i < line2; i+=2)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
        tmpMatrix[i][j] = ((rand() % 10));
    }
}
```

полный код вот :

```
    int line = 0;
    int column = 0;
    
    cout<<"\nEnter the number of lines:";
    cin>>line;
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns:";
    cin>>column;
    
    int**Matrix =new int*[line];
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            Matrix[i] =new int[column];

        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            Matrix[i][j] = ((rand() % 10));
        }
    }
    
     for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(2) << Matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    int line2=2*line;
    
    int** tmpMatrix = new int*[line2];
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            tmpMatrix[i] = new int[column];

        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < line; i+=2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            tmpMatrix[i][j]=Matrix[i][j]; 
        }
    }
    
        for (int i = 1; i < line2; i+=2)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        {
            tmpMatrix[i][j] = ((rand() % 10));
        }
    }
```

Прошу прошения если мой вопрос оформлен некорректно.

Answer (score 3):

```
int line2=2*line;
```

Т.е. удвоенное число. Отлично

```
int** tmpMatrix = new int*[line2];
```

Оно и выделено - все просто замечательно!

```
for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
{
```

Ой. Инициализируем только половину, вторая половина указателей с мусором...

```
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
```

Несмотря на то, что  каждый указатель инициализируется `column` раз - наверное, для надежности и утечки памяти?...

```
        tmpMatrix[i] = new int[column];
```

Comment: Понял свои ошибки, спасибо больше. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать :
1.строка-четная из матрицы ,2-это новая строка ,3 - должна быть 2 из матрицы первой.Как их занести ?